# Store item to local storage after adding a new item using redux toolkit

Tags: reactjs, local-storage, redux-toolkit

I want to store my data in local storage when adding an item. I want to keep my previous item in my array and new items. But I don't know why it returns me double item when adding first item like this.

```js
const cartSlice = createSlice({
  name: 'cart',
  initialState: JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('item')) || {
    products: [],
    quantity: 0,
    total: 0,
    isFetching: false,
  },
  reducers: {
    addProduct: (state, action) => {
      state.products.push(action.payload);
      state.quantity += 1;
      state.total += action.payload.price * action.payload.quantity;
      localStorage.setItem(
        'item',
        JSON.stringify({
          products: [...state.products, action.payload],
          quantity: state.quantity,
          total: state.total,
        }),
      );
    },
```

[image: The result]

Comment: Your action.payload is the same item which is already in state.products. upload the action code to question. try logging action.payload and check if it's same item in the localstorage

Answer (score -1):

**redux-toolkit** reducer is mutable, you push item to products and in **localeStorage** you merge state.products with payload again, your code should be something like that:

```
 addProduct: (state, action) => {
  state.products.push(action.payload);
  state.quantity += 1;
  state.total += action.payload.price * action.payload.quantity;

  localStorage.setItem(
    'item',
    JSON.stringify({
    products: state.products,
      quantity: state.quantity,
      total: state.total,
    }),
  );
```

Comment: Although the reducer in redux-toolkit allows to write mutating code (it actually just looks mutable for convenience, under the hood it doesn't do mutations), this doesn't mean we should put logic with side effects inside. https://redux.js.org/tutorials/fundamentals/part-3-state-actions-reducers#rules-of-reducers